# Ajax Loader not firing in MVC Remote validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I am doing MVC remote validation and I need to check if the username exists or not. I need to show a ajax loader during the validation.

My view

```
  @model Grid.Models.CategoryViewModel

  @using GridMvc.Html

 @{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
    <script>

    $(function () {
        $("#loader").hide();
        $('form').ajaxStart(function () {
            $("#loader").show();
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
          $("#loader").hide();
      });
    })

        @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <img id="loader" src="~/Content/images/loading.gif" />
        <fieldset id="addField">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.CategoryToInsert.CatagoryName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CategoryToInsert.CatagoryName, new { maxlength = 50 })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CategoryToInsert.CatagoryName)
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div id="success-message" style="display: none;">
            This record is successfully saved!!
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    }
```

My controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult IsCategoryUnique(Category category)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return Json("Category is unavailable", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

and the model

```
       public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public Category CategoryToInsert { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> CategoriesToShow { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int CatagoryID { get; set; }

    [Remote("IsCategoryUnique", "Client", HttpMethod = "POST")]
    public string CatagoryName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    public string Color { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [Display(Name = "PrintTemplate")]
    public string PrintTemplate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

The remote validation gets triggered fine, but the ajaxStart and Stop does not trigger. Where am I going wrong ?

seen these, but the same answers still dont work for me

[How to show the ajax loader image while remote validating using data annotation in asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688668/how-to-show-the-ajax-loader-image-while-remote-validating-using-data-annotation)

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? The question you reference is from 2011 and many things have been depreciated in newer versions. We can help you better if we know what version of jQuery we're dealing with.

Comment: ^ Not to nitpick, but I think the word you're looking for is *deprecated*.

Comment: You're right but the point is, in all likelihood, Targarian is trying to use methods that no longer exist in his version of jQuery because they have been replaced with newer ways to do it.

Comment: I am using JQuery 1.9 version.@NickBork

Comment: [From the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) _As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document._ `$(document).ajaxStart(function() {...`